# How to set the `OutDir` in the command link with Mono's xbuild.exe?

Tags: mono, xbuild

I'm trying to build a c# solution in msysgit (Windows) using the same build command that I would with msbuild:

`"C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/msbuild.exe" /p:Configuration=Debug /p:OutDir="c:\projects\proudly\build" "src/Proudly.Identity.sln"`

With msbuild, the output of the build goes into my `/build` folder and all is well. Now, when I run the same command with Mono's xbuild, like this:

`"C:/Program Files (x86)/Mono/lib/mono/xbuild/12.0/bin/xbuild.exe" /p:Configuration=Debug /p:OutDir="c:\projects\proudly\build" "src/Proudly.Identity.sln"`

...and my the build output goes into the `/bin/Debug` folder of each project instead of my build folder.

I was under the impression that xbuild can be using just like msbuild. Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I just tried on a solution of mine and `/p:OutDir` worked just fine with xbuild. I ran it from the "Mono Command Prompt" that is installed by the Mono for Windows installer though.

Comment: I will try in the mono command prompt to see what happens.

Comment: I can get it to work in the command prompt, but not in msysgit. In the command prompt, I see that my command works if I don't specifiy the full path when I execute `xbuild.exe`. But I need this to work in msysgit. :(